# How to return a large number as a type number without scientific notation in typescript (without BigInt)?

Tags: typescript, largenumber

I was trying to complete a challenge and came across this problem which made me return a large number and it mustn't be notated. The return type is `number` (`int`) and you cannot use `BigInt` in the challenge.

```
function add (a: number, b: number, n: number): number {
  let t1 = a;
  let t2 = b;
  for (let i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
    const temp = t2;
    t2 = t1 + t2 * t2;
    t1 = temp;
  }
  return (t2);
}

console.log(add(0,1,10)) // output: 8.426661309628124e+22
```

Is there a way I can do this in typescript?

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCasQCmQLkWEAWwCMBTAJwBpFi8CSLqw6izyBKFh8xAbwChEiADakoiKAEZEAXhQBuQSLESATLJqKhwOD0yjxMDQGZ5iIwB45YMzADUd9nyVCICAM7iopQgAcNUKpaQmoB0nahAFRqwUJSAT6%20wQC%20SuRiIORImIHsiqn8bmDucKIAdMJwAObY6JgADJSSTfXs7PxAA) is an example in which I want to return the number without annotation.

Comment: Can you include a [mre] of what you need? As it is the question is way too broad and vague; there are all sorts of possible things you *might* be asking about.

Comment: @jcalz I've added a link to the description.

Comment: Perhaps you want [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)?

Comment: @jtbandes I couldn't use it in the playground I linked in the description. Could you please change the code and post the link here?

Comment: The return type cannot be `number` if you need to accurately represent an integer in the range of 10^23.  [The largest integer that `number` can safely represent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) is less than 10^14.  So it's just not possible.  If you're okay with a different return type (like a `string` representation of the number) then it's possible, although such things are exactly why `bigint` was introduced. If this is what you need, then you should say so explicitly in the question.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you. I reached the same answer after some research. In the challenge the return type is `number` and I can't change it. I assume it's a problem with the question.

Comment: So then what do you want to do with this question?  Should I post an answer explaining that this is impossible?  Should I post an answer with an implementation that rolls my own large integer math and outputs a long string?  Both? Neither?

Comment: You can do both I think. Just by indicating it's not possible to use `number` as a returned type for a large number answers my question. And by showing a possible workaround anyone having this problem who stumbles on this question will have decent answer too. Thank you in advance